# How to split and keep numbers together

Tags: ruby, string

I am programming a math expression checker. I have this string:

```
Oper = "((234+332)+(cos4-sin65))"
```

I want to split this string by separating all `"()"`s and operators minus numbers or trigonometric ratios to get this result:

```
Oper = ['(', '(', '234', '+', '332', ')', '+', '(', 'cos4', '-', 'sin65', ')', ')']
```

How would the split be?

Comment: what is the logic of this split?

Comment: The program is about math expressions checker and the idea is 
separate all the "()" and operators  minus the numbers or trigonometric ratios

Comment: What's the logic of an input such as `cos4` or `sin65`?  You seem to be treating them as labels or variable names.  How would one know that's not supposed to be evaluating `cosine(4)` and `sine(65)`?

Comment: It is a bad idea to use constant for something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"((234+332)+(cos4-sin65))".split /([[:alpha:]]*\d+)*/
# => ["(", "(", "234", "+", "332", ")", "+", "(", "cos4", "-", "sin65", ")", ")"]
```

Splits the whole string by nothing or optional alphanumeric + digits.

Comment: Thanks, is what I needed

Answer (score 1):

```
oper = "((234+332)+(cos4-sin65))"

oper.scan /[^[:alnum:]]|[[:alnum:]]+/
  #=> ["(", "(", "234", "+", "332", ")", "+", "(", "cos4", "-", "sin65", ")", ")"]
```

Scan for one non-alphanumeric character or one or more alphanumeric characters.